# Rails, place to put user input parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, helper

In my Rails app there is a view with a simple user form consisting of a text box and a submit button.
When the user submits the form, depending on his input, different models are created:

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if is_foo params[:text]
      Foo.create
    else
      Bar.create 
    end
  end

  def is_foo(text)
    # Here the message gets parsed
    # i.e if text[0] == "M"
  end
end
```

My question is, do you think that it's a better design to put the "is_foo" logic inside the Foo model instead of the controller like so?

Model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.is_foo(text)
    # Here the message gets parsed
    # i.e if text[0] == "M"
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    if Foo.is_foo params[:text]
      Foo.create
    else
      Bar.create 
    end
  end
end
```

On one hand, the model should take care of the logic. On the other, this isn't really logic, its more of an input rule... What do you think guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

I'd leave the `is_foo` out of the model, as model logic should be to do with the model directly, not determining which model should be created / saved

I would personally look at using a `helper method` for the test - calling the file `ControllerHelper` or similar:

```
#app/helpers/controller_helper.rb
class ControllerHelper
  def is_foo? text
    # Here the message gets parsed
    # i.e if text[0] == "M"
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call the helper in your controller, giving you the ability to use the logic to form the fixes:

```
#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  include ControllerHelper

  def create
    model = is_foo?(params[:text]) ? "foo" : "bar"
    model.constantize.send(:create)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it a `ControllerHelper` module as mentioned in [Rich Pecks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24340428/766783) (since helpers in Rails are view-related), but something like

```
# app/lib/foo_bar_creator.rb
FooBarCreator = Struct.new(:params) do
  def create
    build.save
  end

  def build
    klass.new
  end

  def is_foo?
    params[:text] == 'foo'
  end

  def klass
    is_foo? ? Foo : Bar
  end
end
```

(some call these kind of classes "Service Objects")

This way I could just call `FooBarCreator.new(params).create` in my controller.